# Walking Distance in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

**Is there a way to collect data from the pedestrian trajectory in cordinates (x, y) without having to program in anylogic?**

I used the database as sugested but it only collects the walked distance (m).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code it yourself... probably you will need a cyclic event in your pedestrian agent that records every second the coordinates of the position and save it to a dataset, a databsase, a collection, an excel file or anything depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe for your help. One more question: Is that possible to code it or find it on here or another anylogic place?

Comment: You might also try using the build-in logging feature. It does record movement distance for normal agents, might do it for peds as well, not sure